# how to give this variable global scope

Tags: c++, scope

In my header file, I have the following:

```
private:
     ImagePixmapItem *item;
```

In a function, I create a new ImagePixmapItem like so:

```
ImagePixmapItem *item(static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p)));
```

However, this creates a local copy of item.
but if I do this:

```
*item(static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p)));
```

I get the following error:

```
error: ‘((ViewerMain*)this)->ViewerMain::item’ cannot be used as a function
```

So what is the correct way to make this call?

Comment: Perhaps you can provide a little bit of context. I hope that `private:` is inside the definition of a `class`. It's hard to tell what you are trying to do or why you need all the casts and pointers.

Comment: yes, private is inside the definition of a class. I am using my own class which extends functionality of a QGraphicsPixmapItem, which is why there are the casts.

Comment: If you are extending, you should use `dynamic_cast` instead of `static_cast`. Also you should review some basic tutorial on pointers, the assertion that "this creates a local copy of item", well, only a copy of the *pointer* to the actual item is performed, the pointed object is still unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An initialization like

```
item(static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p)));
```

is only allowed within the declaration of your variable (this is in fact your first example with a local variable), or (for member fields) in the constructor initialization list:

```
ViewerMain::ViewerMain() :
  item(static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p)))
{
  ... 
}
```

Inside a member function, just assign to it:

```
item = static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p));
```

(Since it is private, it is not accessible from a nonmember function, except if it is friend of the class.)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an assignment:

```
item = static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p));
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's a *member* function of the class, just do:

```
item = static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p));
```

If it's not a member, you'd have to provide a way to assign that private member variable, say, via a setter member method:

```
void setItem( ImagePixmapItem* i ) { item = i; }
```

Comment: And if it's not, of course, it'll have to use a constructor or public member function (depending on how the class is written) to set that value.

Answer (score 0):

Use `*item = static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p));`

unless you do it in your constructor, in which case you can use...

```
ViewerMain::ViewerMain (...):
    item (static_cast<ImagePixmapItem *>(scene.addPixmap(p)))
{}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try and provide more context into what you want to be done and where. You can see that different answers interpret your code as part of the initialization list or a statement in the body of a function --both interpretations are valid without more context.

Now, my interpretation is that you are inside a function and that you want to set the member `item` to refer to the result of the call to `scene.addPixmap(p);`. If that is the case, you should use assignment.

The problem if you follow the first block is that you are creating a local variable that hides the member attribute, and you initialize it, but that does not change the member attribute `item`.

If you remove the type from the declaration, there will be no local `item` in scope, and the compiler will find that the identifier refers to the member attribute, which is what you want. At this stage, the compiler interprets the line: `*item(param)` as calling `operator()` on the attribute `item`, and derreferencing the result. Since `item` is a pointer, it cannot apply the `operator()` and produces the error message: *item cannot be used as a function*.

As others have pointed out, the solution is assigning instead of trying to use the initialization syntax that is only available at the definition point for local variables, or in the initialization list for member attributes.